# Generate Transition matrix of vector for markov chain?

Tags: matrix

y=c(5,5,5,5,4,5,3,5,3,3,4,2,5,5,3,1,1,3,3,4,1,5,1,1,3,3,2,5,1,5,1,5,5,5,5,2,1,4,1,1,1,2,4,5,5,1,4,2,4,1,3,4,2,2,5,2,2,5,5)

p<-matrix(nrow=5,ncol=5,0)
for (t in 1:(length(x)-1)) p[x[t],x[t+1]]<-p[x[t],x[t+1]]+1
for (i in 1:5) p[i,]<-p[i,] / sum(p[i,])

I am working with 5 states.

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to resolve it
Error in p[x[t], x[t + 1]] : subscript out of bounds

Also, has anyone had success using the markovchain packaged to generate transition matrixes?

Comment: you didn't give us an `x`, so the code is not reproducible. Also, this question is more suitable for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

I take it `y` is your vector of states at each time step.

What I would do is create a `data.frame` where each row corresponds to a state transition like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    t.one = y[-length(y)],
    t.next = y[-1],
    p = 1 / (length(y) - 1)  # 1 / <number of transitions>
)
```

Then aggregate by each possible transition:

```
pr.df <- aggregate(p ~ t.one + t.next, data=df, FUN=sum)
```

Then create a matrix and fill it with your aggregated data:

```
mat <- matrix(nrow=5, ncol=5, 0)

for (k in 1:nrow(pr.df)) {
    i <- pr.df$t.one[k]
    j <- pr.df$t.next[k]
    mat[i,j] <- pr.df$p[k]
}
```

and verify that your probabilities sum to 1.0: `sum(mat)`